# Pair wise Ranking for Images

Tags: machine-learning

I wanted to know whether there are any algorithms using machine learning which can rank a particular set of images given there quality  and other features using pairwise comparision like Learning to Rank algorithms (RankNet,LambdaRank and LambdaMART) and can these LTR algos be used for image ranking too and any good sources to find the implementation level explaination.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used BRISQUE method to assess image quality. You can combine that with any other desired model of your choice and ensemble the result to form a ranking. Here is a detailed implementation and working of BRISQUE method.

https://towardsdatascience.com/automatic-image-quality-assessment-in-python-391a6be52c11

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But i already have image quality features and their categories i just want an appropriate model to rank them